# wijmo grid - convert rows to columns and columns to rows in wijmo grid

Tags: wijmo, wijmo-grid

I am using wijmo grid in my angular4 application. The problem is that while converting rows to columns and columns to rows in wijmo grid. How can I achieve transpose of wijmo grid..?

```
  data = this.getData();
  getData() {
    let countries = 'US,Germany,UK,Japan,Italy,Greece'.split(','),
    data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      data.push({
        country: countries[i],
        sales: Math.random() * 10000,
        expenses: Math.random() * 5000,
        downloads: Math.round(Math.random() * 20000)
      });
    }
    return new CollectionView(data);
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <wj-flex-grid [itemsSource]="data">
 </wj-flex-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

On various requests from the Wijmo users, Wijmo team created a demo sample for transposed view of FlexGrid. Please refer to the following demo fiddle sample for reference:
`Code`https://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/tce6ro57/